# I am making a CRUD web application in React using axios. I'm getting the following error: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

ERROR:
[TypeError: Object(...) is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4RqI.png)

Here is my code:

**api**.js file

```
import axios from "axios";

//url call to the server
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:9000/postmessages";


export default {
  postMessage(url = baseUrl) {
    return {
      fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
      fetchById: (id) => axios.get(url + id)
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the **postMessage**.js file

```
//import api module
import api from "./api";

//fetchall records with a get request
export const fetchall = () => (dispatch) => {
  api()
  .postMessage()
    .fetchall()
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("postMessage api");
      dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

what am i doing wrong or is there any alternative way which is better than what i'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `api.js` you're exporting an object :

```
export default { //this is an exported object not function
       ...
}
```

then you're calling it as function using `()`, so you've to remove them and use it like :

```
 api.postMessage()...
```

detailed :

```
//import api module
import api from "./api";

//fetchall records with a get request
export const fetchall = () => (dispatch) => {
  api // omit the ()
  .postMessage()
    .fetchall()
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("postMessage api");
      dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```